# Autofill username and password using queryselector by id

Tags: javascript, ios, autocomplete, shortcut, queryselectall

I’m trying to create some simple javascript to autofill a webpage.

I’d like to modify the following for use with a specific elementid for the username ‘password_username’ and password ‘password_password’

```
var result = [];

// Get all links from the page need to change to specific for username

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (let element of elements) {
element.value = "username";
}

// Get all links from the page need to change to specific for password

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (let element of elements) {
element.value = "password";
}

// Call completion to finish
completion(result) `
```

I’ve only just started to learn code and have very basic javascript knowledge, any help is appreciated!

Cheers,

Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this will work as imagined as I can't test it out right now, but give it a shot:

```
const usernameElements = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="text"]`);
const passwordElements = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="password"]`);

usernameElements.forEach(username => username.value = "the user name");
passwordElements.forEach(password => password.value = "the password");
```

It selects the input fields according to the type (text/password) and adds the value to them. Now I am not entirely sure if this that you posted is part of a bigger script, but this might do the trick that you need. You'd need to make the `username` and `password` variables to dynamically load, if you want different usernames and passwords, otherwise this adds the values that you give it, like for example `username.value = "testing username"` and `password.value = "testing password"` . Cheers.

Comment: Hi Petar, thanks for responding, your code worked spot on!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I was also trying to be specific and update a field with the id = "password_username" and "password_password" for the password and username fields respectively so I changed the input[type="text"] to input[id="password_username"].  Next i'm going to try and add code to automatically click a button to login, if you've got any experience doing so your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this button login something that you'd like to add to your own website, or to use it so you could automatically fill the boxes when you want to log in somewhere? If its the second case, I am not sure, but I think that you can't achieve that, as you'd basically need to "insert" that button to the website. What you (possibly) could do, is make some sort of google chrome extension for example, that'd do the job for you. Check out Brad Traversy on youtube, he has a video about making a Google Chrome extension.

Comment: It was the second case. I’ll take a look at that cheers! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question correctly.

To select a specific field by id and set a value to it, you may use `document.querySelector("#the_id").value = "the_value";`

If you have an object with {id: value} structure, you can process it in a loop:

```js
const creds = {
  id1: 'val1',
  id2: 'val2' // ...
};

for (const [id, val] of Object.entries(creds)) {
  document.querySelector(`#${id}`).value = val;
}
```

Please clarify if I did not understand what you need, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Hi Nikita, thanks for responding! I couldn't quite get your code to work but I'm going to try and change it to work in my case, i'm still learning so appreciate your example.